# unable to update boolean variable with actionfunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, actionfunction

I'm trying to update the boolean value named selected in wrapper class action support and onclick functions. Here is my code. Please let me know how to handle this

```
<apex:outputPanel id="table2">
        <div class="slds-pill_container" id="refresh">
          <apex:repeat value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="c" id="repeatTable2">
            <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-pill__action"
                title="Full pill label verbiage mirrored here">
                <span class="slds-pill__label">{!c.LeadName}</span>
              </a>
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove" title="Remove">
                 <a onclick="myActionFunction('{!c.selected}');" value="{!c.selected}" >
                <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}">
                  </use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
                </a>
              </button>
            </span>
          </apex:repeat>
          <apex:actionFunction name="myActionFunction" action="{!processUnselected}" reRender="table,table2"  >
                <apex:param name="selected" value=""/>
                </apex:actionFunction>
        </div>
      </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an actionFunction like this, because those methods don't have context: you can't tell which wrapper should be updated.

## Option 1

Use an apex:commandLink instead.

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="{!c.toggleSelected}" value="{!c.selected}" >
```

Inside your wrapper class, add the method:

```
public void toggleSelected() {
  selected = !selected;
}
```

## Option 2

Include the wrapper index to update:

```
onclick="myActionFunction({!indexVar});
```

Since you already know what the state is, you don't need to pass that in as a parameter; just toggle it directly.

```
public void myActionFunctionHandler(Integer index) {
    selectedAccounts[index].selected = !selectedAccounts[index].selected;
}
```